# Is Cordova-Safe still working with Ionic3?

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, encryption, ionic3

I wanted to encrypt some files on my Android phone using Ionic3 with the cordova-safe Plugin.

Here's what I've done:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-safe
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-encryption
```

**-> config.xml**

```
[...]
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-safe" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.0.4" />
[...]
```

**-> app.modules.ts**

```
[...]
import { FileEncryption } from '@ionic-native/file-encryption';
[...]
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    File,
    FileEncryption,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
[...]
```

**-> home.ts**

```
[...]
handler: data => {
            console.log("[INFO] Encrypt clicked");
            this.fileEncryption.encrypt(this.file.dataDirectory + item, data.title);
          }
[...]
```

**And this is what I get in logcat:**

> [INFO] Encrypt clicked"
>   "Native: tried calling FileEncryption.encrypt, but the FileEncryption
>   plugin is not installed."
>   "Install the FileEncryption plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-safe'"

I have already removed and added the Plugin and the Platform.
And I do not want to create this project new.

Some more Information about my OS:

I'm currently running Arch GNU/Linux with Linux 4.11.7-1-ARCH.
I'm using Cordova 7.0.1
and Ionic 3.4.2